# Clipping a raster with shapefile and export the raster with shapefile extent

Tags: arcpy, raster, clip, extents

I am clipping a raster file with a shapefile grid and I want to **save each raster subset individually with the polygon spatial extent**.

To select the extent of each polygon, first I select the polygon with `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management` and then I get the polygon extent and I use this extent in `arcpy.Clip_management` function.

But when I run the code each raster subset don't have the extent that I want.

The code is:

`def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""`

```
a= parameters[0].valueAsText
b= parameters[1].valueAsText`
#-----------------------------

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(a, ["FID_malla"]) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:

        #select a polygon                           
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(a, "NEW_SELECTION", '"FID_malla" ='+str(row[0]))

        #extent
        shp_ex = arcpy.Describe(a)
        exshp = shp_ex.extent

        xmin=exshp.XMin
        ymin=exshp.YMin
        xmax=exshp.XMax
        ymax=exshp.YMax


        ExtStr = "{} {} {} {}".format(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)


        #Execute clip
        arcpy.Clip_management(b, ExtStr, "C:\Users\mvinuales\Desktop\Image_Chips\imagen\\" + str(row[0]) +".tif", a, "256", "ClippingGeometry","NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")

    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(a,"CLEAR_SELECTION")
```

Comment: What extent do you get?

Comment: You could use the SHAPE@ token to pull back polygon geometries, look at their extent property, and bypass Select Layer By Attribute.  What do test values of `a` and `b` look like?

Comment: @BERA, I get the extent of the raster image (b). @PolyGeo, I use "SHAPE@" and I calculate the extent as `row[1].extent`, but its continues being raster's extent. `a= parameters[0].valueAsText` is a shapefile with some polygons and `b= parameters[1].valueAsText` is a raster image.

Answer (score 1):

You should only need three parameters in Clip to clip by a rectangle: `in_raster`, `rectangle` and `out_raster`. Try leaving the others as default.

Your selection might not be working. Use three double quotes and AddFieldDelimiters to get it right:

```
...
import os

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(a, 'FID_malla') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        sql = """{0}={1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(a,'FID_malla'), row[0])
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(a, "NEW_SELECTION", sql)
        shp_ex = arcpy.Describe(a)
        exshp = shp_ex.extent
        ExtStr = "{} {} {} {}".format(exshp.XMin,exshp.YMin,exshp.XMax,exshp.YMax)
        arcpy.Clip_management(in_raster=b, rectangle=ExtStr, out_raster=os.path.join(r"C:\Users\mvinuales\Desktop\Image_Chips\imagen", str(row[0]) +".tif"))
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(a,"CLEAR_SELECTION")
```

And as mentioned by @PolyGeo in the comments you can also use the SHAPE@ token. There is no need for selections:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(a, ['FID_malla','SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        e = row[1].extent
        ExtStr = "{} {} {} {}".format(e.XMin,e.YMin,e.XMax,e.YMax)
        arcpy.Clip_management(in_raster=b, rectangle=ExtStr, out_raster=os.path.join(r"C:\Users\mvinuales\Desktop\Image_Chips\imagen", str(row[0]) +".tif"))
```

Answer (score 0):

@BERA, thanks for your sugestions. I think that the selection is correct because I get different raster subsects with their particular names. But I have seen that in `arcpy.Clip_management` the second argument ("EXTENT") **need enter the values with (,) not with (.)**, so I replace it.

But when I run the code the extent of the raster subset is the whole extent of the **Input raster**.
Maybe with `ExtStr = "{} {} {} {}".format(xmi,ymi,xma,yma)` I don't pass correct the argument.

The code is:

```
a= parameters[0].valueAsText
b= parameters[1].valueAsText
#-----------------------------`


with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(a, ["FID_malla","SHAPE@"]) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:

        #select a polygon                           
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(a, "NEW_SELECTION", '"FID_malla" ='+str(row[0]))

        #extent
        extent = row[1].extent


        xmin=extent.XMin
        ymin=extent.YMin
        xmax=extent.XMax
        ymax=extent.YMax

        xi=str(xmin)
        yi=str(ymin)
        xa=str(xmax)
        ya=str(ymax)

        xmi=xi.replace(".",",")
        ymi=yi.replace(".",",")
        xma=xa.replace(".",",")
        yma=ya.replace(".",",")


        ExtStr = "{} {} {} {}".format(xmi,ymi,xma,yma)


        arcpy.Clip_management(b, ExtStr, "C:\Users\mvinuales\Desktop\Image_Chips\imagen\\" + str(row[0]) +".tif", a, "256", "ClippingGeometry","NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")`


    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(a,"CLEAR_SELECTION")
```